# What is the difference between a Class and a Singleton in Objective-C?

Tags: objective-c, class, singleton

I've read several threads about the differences between Singletons and Classes in various languages, but none (that I can find) specific to Objective-C.

They seem very similar to me.

I'm new to objective-c - so what are the differences, or usage cases between Singletons and Classes?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are programming in Objective-C, an Object-oriented programming language (OOP). So, to know what a class is, you must first understand OOP concepts.

I wont go into why **OOP languages** was developed as opposed to **procedural** languages. You can google "procedural vs objective oriented advantages".

Anyway,
Object Oriented Programming languages (OOP) provide mechanisms/devices/structures that helps you implement OOP principles. 3 main principles are (1)**Encapsulation** (2)**Inheritance** (3) **Polymorphism**. Again google to find out what these are.

Now a **Class**: would be one of those mechanisms/devices/structures that implements the 3 OOP principles. It is a blueprint/design/structure of what an **object** should be. 
Typically (but not always) a class would have (1) variables declared within it (strings, int, arrays, whatever) and (2) Methods/functions that perform a task on those declared variables within it. When you instantiate/allocate/create-that-class-in-memory, that class becomes "alive". The blueprints now become an **object** (an object that implements the OOP principles you are supposed to google).

Now a **Singleton** is a design pattern. If you're a coming from a procedural language environment, there are many programming design patterns you may need to catch up on. A Singleton is a pattern/a-particular-way-you-design-someting. So when you say a singleton class, it is a particular way you design that class. And what is that particular design? Well, usually when you instantiate/allocate/create-a-class-in-memory, you can do it many times, there by creating multiple instanced objects of that class. If you apply a singleton design pattern to a class however, you ensure that only one instance (and ONLY one) can be created.

In Objective-C if i do something like this:

```
myClass *anObjectOfMyClass1 = [[myClass alloc] init];
// This (above) would create an object from the blueprint *myClass* and assign it to *anObjectOfMyClass1*
myClass *anObjectOfMyClass2 = [[myClass alloc] init];
// This would create an object from the blueprint *myClass* and assign it to *anObjectOfMyClass2*
// Note: anObjectOfMyClass1 and anObjectOfMyClass2 would contain two different objects of the same type
// If *myClass* was designed using  singleton pattern however, anObjectOfMyClass1 and anObjectOfMyClass2 would typically contain the same object.
```

In short.. you really cant compare the two.
As for the usage of singletons.. I would say Loggers. I think there are already answers around stackoverflow about uses of singletons. Look around a bit.

Answer (score 2):

In every programming language I've heard of, a singleton is a [design pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern) which dictates that only a single instance exists for a given class - whereas in *a normal* class, many instances of it can be created.

**EDIT :**

As was mentioned in the comments, [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/General/Conceptual/DevPedia-CocoaCore/Singleton.html) is the relevant quote from the documentation:

> A singleton class returns the same instance no matter how many times an application requests it. A typical class permits callers to create as many instances of the class as they want, whereas with a singleton class, there can be only one instance of the class per process. A singleton object provides a global point of access to the resources of its class. Singletons are used in situations where this single point of control is desirable, such as with classes that offer some general service or resource

Comment: And the same is entirely true of Objective-C. See Apple's Cocoa Core Competencies entry for Singleton: http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/General/Conceptual/DevPedia-CocoaCore/Singleton.html

Answer (score 1):

Singleton is a design pattern, class is a paradigm of object oriented programming. You can't really compare the two.

Answer (score 0):

Object Oriented concepts and patterns are abstract from the techologies/language you use to  implemented them .In other words the meaning of a `Class` is the same in all the Object Oriented language and the `Singleton` is a pattern that can be implemented in any Object Oriented Language

Answer (score 0):

Well, a class is the structure of definition. Think of it as a blueprint for a chair or something. Your chair is the Object, and the "blueprints" is the class. Singleton is a class pattern, so a way of doing classes.

A singleton has basically a pointer to an instance of it self in the class. And you have a method to get that instance. But you cannot create a new object of this class. You can only get the one object. It's a kinda like having a global variable. You always have access to that one object.

I use singleton a lot for language classes, translation classes, etc

**EDIT**

Never done much Objective-C, but it's still object oriented programming, so it would be same pattern in any language.

Personally, I'd go with the Singleton, if you want to share it between multiple views. I have a pattern which looks like a singleton, but for multiple instances. For my Locale class in one of my project, I have more than one Locale instances, but I have one getInstance method in my Locale class (the constructor is private, so I cannot initialize this class outside of it selfs). So I pass what locale I want to the getInstance method, and it checks a private array that contains all the previous instance, if it's not in the array, well it creates a new instance of that Locale and add it to the array. So it's the same as a Singleton, but with an array of instances and not just one instance.

Comment: My goal is to have a grouping of data, multiple instances of that group, and share it between views. For example, name,date,location as a group, then an array of groups which can be accessed and changed from multiple views. What is the best way to do this in objective-c? (Should this be a separate Question?)

Comment: Thanks for the additional info...I'll ask a separate question to get more details in Objective-C.